# Unable to understand javascript syntax

Tags: javascript

I was going through the code of [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form).I came across following lines which I am unable to comprehend.

```
var formData = (0, _utils.getDefaultFormState)(schema, props.formData, definitions);
```

How is content within the first bracket a function to which arguments(schema, props.formData etc.) are passed?

Comment: first braces `()` returns a function which accepts 3 arguments.

Comment: The expression `(n0, n1, ..., n)` evaluates to `n`, so in your case, the function `_utils.getDefaultFormState`. As for why this is used, I'm not sure

Comment: Phil your comment would be worthy as an answer in it's own right.

Comment: What is the point of having the starting 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer to this question is that in the first expression `(0,_utils.getDefaultFormState)` the  [**comma**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) `,` operator evaluates to the last argument and returns it.

So, comma operator operates on it's operands from left to right and returns the <del>last</del> right most evaluated operand in the expression.

But that is different in terms of using functions and its returned values.

```
// sample from MDN.
function myFunc() {
  var x = 0;

  return (x += 1, x); // the same as return ++x;
}
```

As i mentioned in the comment:

*First brackets are self executing function and it returns it's value as a function of `_utils` object, which accepts 3 or more arguments.*

Answer (score 1):

In that context the first parenthesis pair is a sequence of statement whose value is the value of the last expression. Then:

```
(0,_utils.getDefaultFormState)
```

returns the function objet `_utils.getDefaultFormState` which is then called with the following arguments.